# Directed Graph Versus Associative Array

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have been reading up on directed graphs.  I have managed to get an abstract graph data type working in my application but I don't find it particularly intuitive and am considering replacing it with an ordinary multi-dimensional array.

My graph is sparse and acyclic.  Each vertex is reachable from one particular 'master' vertex.  If it was a tree, this master vertex would be the 'root'.  It it was a social network, this master vertex would be 'me'.

Although my graph may have hundreds of thousands of vertices it has a finite depth: the greatest distance between any two nodes is 3 edges.

The underlying data representation is an adjacency list.  A small example would look like this:

```
Head | Tails
--------------
  1  | 2, 3, 4
  2  | 5  
  3  | 5
  4  | 5
  5  | 6
```

If I was using an ordinary multi-dim array instead of my graph data type, it would look something like this:

```
$me[1][2][5][6]
$me[1][3][5][6]
$me[1][4][5][6]
```

Now, the main things that I want to be able to do with this graph are:

1. Navigate it as a hierarchy.  I realise that some child vertices will feature in more than one category (e.g. #5), but that is what I want for this particular use case.  I can't see any real difference between an array and a graph for this point.
2. Lay it out as a list (alphabetical, according to vertex name), with no duplicates.  I would probably do a DFS, flagging visited vertices as I go, to avoid exploring them more than once.  But as far as I can see this is achievable using either the graph or the array, and at the same cost.
3. Do an 'all paths' analysis for any given pair of points.  Because I want 'all paths' (ie. I'm not simply checking for reachability), it seems to me that I have to traverse the entire graph, and again I can see no advantage in a graph over an array.

I get the feeling that I am missing something, but I can't put my finger on it.  Can you???  Any ideas, suggestions, insights or advice gratefully accepted...  (By the way, I'm using PHP, and the data source is a relational DB.  I don't think this makes any real difference though).

Thanks!

Comment: What are the dimensions of this multiple dimensions array? Usually the alternatives for graph are a matrix (2 dimensions) or adjancy list (which is basically an implementation of a sparsed matrix...)

Answer (score 2):

One thing you need to understand is that a *directed graph* (or digraph) is a **concept**, whereas an *associative array* is a **data structure**.

An instance of the digraph concept can be stored in many different data structures,  of which you can find the most common on this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29#Representations).

I'm not sure what you are doing with your multidimensional array... storing all paths? You will end up with a N³ space complexity, and trouble building it. A tree-based structure would be more efficient at the very least.

Now to the things you want to do with your graph:

1. **Navigate as a hierarchy**. The basic digraph concept doesn't allow to go up in the hierarchy, but  you can easily store the reverse graph as well (especially with matrix-based representations, just use 3 values instead of 2 - forward, backward and nothing) .
2. **Lay it out as a list, according to name**. You have to store the name somewhere (either in a side map or in the vertex object), but it shouldn't be any harder than sorting anything else according to name.
3. **Do an 'all paths' analysis**. You can probably get away with linear complexity (in the number of paths) through DP and a shared representation of paths.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that your data structure is too complicated. If you represent a directed graph as a multidimensional array, it is almost always of dimension two so that

```
$array[$x][$y]
```

is a boolean value that is TRUE if and only if there is an edge from node $x to node $y in the graph. In your example if would be e.g.

```
$array[1][2] = TRUE
$array[1][5] = FALSE
```

But for sparse graphs, using this boolean matrix representation is not usually good. Typically you would have a one-dimensional array that maps every node to a set of nodes to which there is an edge, e.g.

```
$array[1] = { 2, 3, 4 }
```

where { ... } means some sort of an unordered collection data structure, which can be e.g. a binary search tree or a hash set (hash table).

This data structure enables you to quickly find the nodes to which there is an arc from a given node, which is a key feature for graph algorithms.

Sometimes you want to be able to traverse your graph backwards also; in that case you would have another array that maps nodes to the list of their predecessors.